# what is the use of encapsulation here

Tags: unity-game-engine

What is the use of constructor here ?

This is script A :

```
[SerializeField]
private LobbyFunction _lobbyFunction;
public  LobbyFunction LobbyFunction
{
    get { return _lobbyFunction; }
}
```

This is script B:

```
private void Start()
{
    GameObject lobbyCanvasGO = CanvasManager.Instance.LobbyFunction.gameObject;
    if (lobbyCanvasGO == null) return;
}
```

what if I choose not to use the encapsulation ? no error , I guess .Any help would be greatly appreciated ,thanks!

**edit:** I guess using encapsulation here make the var read- only  , only get... and therefore increase the security , people from outside can't change the value  ,is it the ans?

Comment: What constructor? There is no constructor in this code.

Comment: @tkausl {get; set; } , isn't it a constructor ?

Comment: No, this is a [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) .. in your case it is for granting Read-Only access to the private backing field `:lobbyFunction`

Comment: @derHugo so that the access modifier is public , I can use the value (set and get) in other script but people except me just can't change the value , is it right

Comment: no .. since there is no `set` defined for this property any other class can only see the `get` and thus can only read the value, not assign it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no constructor but a [**Property**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties)

> A property is a member that provides a flexible mechanism to read, write, or compute the value of a private field. Properties can be used as if they are public data members, but they are actually special methods called accessors. This enables data to be accessed easily and still helps promote the safety and flexibility of methods.

In your case it is for granting **Read-Only** access to the `private` backing field `_lobbyFunction` so no other class can change its value since only the class "A" containing `_lobbyFunction` itself is allowed to assign it.

Btw the way you have it it is equivalent to simply write

```
public LobbyFunction LobbyFunction { get; private set; }
```

without the need for a backing field. Then still only the containing class "A" itself is allowed to assign a value while everyone else can read it.